# UrlFetchApp exception in Google Data Studio connector

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, looker-studio

I am developing a connector which in order to get data needs to make two separate calls to API. I noticed that from time to time i get a following error:

```
    { [Exception: Address unavailable: https://myapi.call] name: 'Exception' }
```

This response has nothing to do with the API that is called because I get a valid `200` response for this call so the error must originate from `UrlFetchApp` that I am using to fetch data. Also it only happens with more complicated reports which require many simultaneous calls to API. So I thought maybe I hit some quota and decided to use `Utilities.sleep()`. However it seems only to work within the same execution context. So for example if i have a one report there will be only one `getData()` execution so my`Utilities.sleep()` will work fine:

[image]

As you see there is a 1 sec gap that I specified. However for the same code when I have several reports in Data Studio dashboard the result is following:

[image]

As you see there seems to be 12 execution contexts firing simultaneously. So me `Utilities.sleep()` function cannot prevent it. It is very problematic because, first I am gonna exceed the limits of API that I call sooner or later, second it seems I already exceeded limits of `UrlFetchApp`.
Has anyone come up with a solution to this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you making the requests in the same script project? Could you please share the script to help you better? In which line is the error showing? Is it in the line where `fetch` method is used?

Comment: 1. Yep. This is one Google Data Studio connector using one data source making several calls to this source. 2. Not at the moment it uses Oauth credentials that I don't want to disclose. I would have to prepare another demo version of the script but it may take time. 3. In my `try catch` statement. If I remove it the error is showing on the line where `UrlFetchApp` is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data Studio will make separate getData calls for each element on a page that uses your connector. To avoid hitting rate limits or quota,use [Lock Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock) and if possible [Apps Script cache](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache).

See the [Chrome UX Connector's code](https://github.com/googledatastudio/community-connectors/tree/master/chrome-ux-report) for examples of both.

Comment: Thanks this Chrome UX Connector is really valuable example. One thing is confusing me though. It utilizes `getScriptCache()` for caching. Does that mean that this cache is shared among users since it is script scoped? Thais would not be desireble for me since my connector fetches user private data.

Comment: You can scope it to user level. Have a look at the reference docs here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/cache-service